# long long data type isn't enough. How to not lose precision?

Tags: c, precision

After playing a bit with the Fibonacci, a `long long` value isn't enough. Is there any workaround to keep adding numbers?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4rlv.png)

Answer (score 2):

Hava a look at [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library

Frome their website: 
"GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface. "